# Is there a way to cause Guice to preserve annotations?

Tags: java, annotations, jax-rs, guice

I'm trying to iterate over all classes that are annotated by an interface `Bar`, initialize them with Guice's `Injector.createInstance`, and register them with a Dropwizard Jersey server.

However, Guice's `Injector.createInstance` method seems to discard JAX-RS as well as custom annotations on every class. For some reason, the only thing that is preserved by Guice is the `@MediaType` annotation. The `@Path` annotation is lost, which prevents Jersey from properly handling HTTP requests.

Is there a way to force Guice to keep all existing annotations on these classes in its own generated implementation? Note that the injector was not configured to specifically handle instances of `Foo`, but the constructor of `Foo` is marked for injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Guice doesn't support this (yet)](https://github.com/google/guice/issues/201)

Guice has an [open issue on this topic](https://github.com/google/guice/issues/201) for more than 10 years and it's not resolved, and will probably never be.

The only workaround is to use the [`@Inherited`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/annotation/Inherited.html) annotation on your annotations.

But you mention you use existing annotations, not custom ones, so let's check them: [`@Consumes`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/Consumes.html) is `@Inherited` (great!), and so is [`@Produces`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/Produces.html) (also great!), but [`@Path`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/Path.html) isn't (booh!), so indeed `@Path` isn't present on your Guice proxies.

The only advice I could give you is to get rid of your Guice-AOP (TypeListener). If you can do that, then you very likely won't have any Guice proxies, and your methods will be on the top object, and therefore visible to Jersey.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because it answers the question that I posed. However, surprisingly, the issue wasn't caused by the injection library at all. I am still facing it when using manually constructed objects. And perhaps more surprisingly, Guice's proxies are still capable of working with Jersey in other projects as well as my own (the error message on the desired paths is not a 404, which means Jersey is able to "read" the correct path from the proxy objects).